# How can I separate multiple quote blocks?

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

I have a series of quotes which I want to display in two separate quote blocks.

```
> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
> really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
> - mweiss
> 
> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [tag:word-online]. -ale
> 
> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss
```

When I try to add these to my post, they display as a single combined quote.

> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
>   really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
>   - mweiss
>
> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [word-online](/questions/tagged/word-online). -ale
>
> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss

**How can I separate quotes so that they aren't combined into a single quote block?**

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How can I write two separate blockquotes in sequence using markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12979577/3357935)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use comment markup `<!-- -->` and an extra whiteline between the quote blocks:

```
> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
> really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
> - mweiss    

<!--  -->
> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [tag:word-online]. -ale

<!--  -->
> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss
```

> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
>   really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
>   - mweiss

> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [word-online](/questions/tagged/word-online). -ale

> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss

Notice that this solution doesn't render any extra html tag between the blockquotes, resulting in the best minimal whitespace possible. Consider one of the other answers if you feel you need more separation between the blocks.

Answer (score 17):

Is this what you wanted?

```
> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
> really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
> - mweiss

<span></span>
> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [tag:word-online]. -ale

<span></span>
> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss
```

> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
>   really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
>   - mweiss

> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [word-online](/questions/tagged/word-online). -ale

> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss

Edit: You can also put a `<div>` tag, it doesn't need a blank line before. Thanks to [@Arulkumar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298962/how-can-i-separate-multiple-quote-blocks#comment971732_298965) in the comments.

Comment: Huh, never would have thought to use `<span>`. Great answer!

Comment: [`<div></div>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBZI3.png) is the other option, that doesn't require to add an empty line before the `<span></span>`

Comment: There are infinite options. It works because it breaks them up and then the system removes the span and div as invalid HTML. You could also use `<lol></lol>` or `<!-- -->` or `<it really doesn't matter what you put here>`.

Answer (score 7):

[Starting June 3rd, 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348750/350567) on Meta Stack Exchange*, you can just use the most intuitive format with a blank line between the blockquotes.

```
> First block

> Second block
```

Renders as:

> First block

> Second block

This is because Stack Exchange's old (self-developed) Markdown renderer handled it differently, while the CommonMark specification defines a different (current) syntax.

And you're probably thinking that all existing answers are no longer correct or necessary. That's right. No more "tricks" with `<!-- -->` or `<p></p>`.

* <sup>Refer to the same link about availability of CommonMark on other Stack sites.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do it in the toolbar.

You can try adding a non breakable space after each blockquote

```
> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
> really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
> - mweiss

&nbsp;


> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [tag:word-online]. -ale

&nbsp;

> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss
```

Which will render as

> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
>   really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
>   - mweiss

> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [word-online](/questions/tagged/word-online). -ale

> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss

Answer (score 2):

Use **paragraphs**

```
> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
> really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
> - mweiss
<p></p>
> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [tag:word-online]. -ale
<p></p>
> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss
```

Yields

> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
>   really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
>   - mweiss

> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [word-online](/questions/tagged/word-online). -ale

> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss

However, the canonical use of `<p>` tag is wrapping content inside it.

```
<p>
> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
> really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
> - mweiss
</p>
<p>
> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [tag:word-online]. -ale
</p>
<p>
> Thanks! I'm sorry I missed that tag. -mweiss
</p>
```