# Markdown: blockquote in list item other than at end

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

In markdown, it is easy to make a blockquote in an indented block, but only if that's at its end. Can we waive that restriction?

---

Visual illustration:

1. Indented block with citation at end

   > I would have written you a shorter letter, but I didn't have enough time.
2. Other indented bloc

   > Hit the road, jack, and don't you come back no more.
3. Yet another

Can we make something that renders similarly, except for whitespace where there is "2.", the "3." becoming "2.", and if possible a little less vertical spacing after the first blockquote?

> The best things in life are free.

Observe that in the body there is no such issue, and slightly less vertical spacing below a blockquote like the above.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298966/158100?

Comment: @rene: Not quite exactly, but close enough that most probably it can be adapted; will post an answer tomorrow, if nobody did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean something like this:

1. Indented block with citation at end

   > I would have written you a shorter letter, but I didn't have enough time.

   Other indented bloc

   > Hit the road, jack, and don't you come back no more.
2. Yet another

Just indent `Other indented bloc` instead of marking it as a list entry:

```
1. Indented block with citation at end
> I would have written you a shorter letter, but I didn't have enough time.

  Other indented bloc
> Hit the road, jack, and don't you come back no more.
3. Yet another
```

Comment: These spaces before `Other indented bloc` make all the difference! Had missed that. There remains a little more vertical spacing before "Other indented bloc" than in the original's body before "Observe that..", but that's only a minor inconsistency.